# Why does $q.all(promises).then() not wait for the promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have to work with AngularJS 1.5.5.
I am calling multiple Rest-Services and need to work with all the results at the same time.

```
$scope.callWebservices = function(){
    let promises = {
        first: callFirstWebservice(),
        second: callSecondWebservice()
    }
    $q.all(promises).then(function(results){
        console.log(results.first);
        console.log(results.second);
        console.log(results.second.value);
    });
}

function callFirstWebservice(){
    return myService.get({
        myParameter : $scope.myId
    }, function(res){
    }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
}
function callSecondWebservice(){
    return myService.get({
        myParameter : $scope.myId
    }, function(res){
    }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

If I call `callWebservices` the chrome dev-console logs two unresolved promises like this: `m {$promise: d, $resolved: false}`
and the third log is a TypeError, because `result.second` is undefined.
When I expand the logoutputs of the promises it refreshes the state and shows `$resolved: true`.

Shouldn't `.then()` wait for all promises to be resolved, before executing?
Am I missing something?

EDIT: Corrected a typo (result != results) that is not present in the original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The methods callFirstWebservice and callSecondWebservice
seem to return a $resource instance.
I had to add `.$promise` to the returnvalue as stated in the angular docs for $resource:

*The Resource instances and collections have these additional properties:
$promise: the promise of the original server interaction that created this instance or collection.*

After changing these to

```
function callFirstWebservice(){
    return myService.get({
        myParameter : $scope.myId
    }, function(res){
    }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }).$promise;
}
function callSecondWebservice(){
    return myService.get({
        myParameter : $scope.myId
    }, function(res){
    }, function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }).$promise;
}
```

everything is working as intended!